# Count number of events retrospectively by an hour in Trino

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I would like to count the number of rows with the same attribute and with a timestamp that is maximum one hour away from the row timestamp, retrospectively.

As an example, given the table:

| Timestamp | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-17 01:51:44 | A |
| 2021-04-17 01:58:43 | A |
| 2021-04-17 02:01:32 | B |
| 2021-04-17 02:15:44 | A |
| 2021-04-17 02:57:44 | A |
| 2021-04-17 02:59:44 | B |
| 2021-04-17 03:15:44 | B |
| 2021-04-17 03:27:44 | A |
| 2021-04-17 03:31:44 | A |
| 2021-04-17 03:45:44 | B |
| 2021-04-17 03:52:44 | B |
| 2021-04-17 04:01:44 | B |
| 2021-04-17 04:23:44 | A |

I would like the query to return something like:

| Timestamp | ID | Occurrencies of ID in prior hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-17 01:51:44 | A | 1 |
| 2021-04-17 01:58:43 | A | 2 |
| 2021-04-17 02:01:32 | B | 1 |
| 2021-04-17 02:15:44 | A | 3 |
| 2021-04-17 02:57:44 | A | 3 |
| 2021-04-17 02:59:44 | B | 2 |
| 2021-04-17 03:15:44 | B | 2 |
| 2021-04-17 03:27:44 | A | 2 |
| 2021-04-17 03:31:44 | A | 3 |
| 2021-04-17 03:45:44 | B | 3 |
| 2021-04-17 03:52:44 | B | 4 |
| 2021-04-17 04:01:44 | B | 4 |
| 2021-04-17 04:23:44 | A | 3 |

I was thinking of joining the table on itself, or use partition as an alternative, but didn't manage to get what I want to achieve.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY ts
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Conceptually, what it does is:

- For every row, look at all rows with the same `id`
- Order the rows by `ts` (ascending)
- Restrict the window to all the rows whose `ts` is between 1 hour before the `ts` of the row and the `ts` of the row
- Compute the count of rows in that frame.

Here's a full example:

```sql
WITH t(ts, id) AS (
  VALUES
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 01:51:44', 'A'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 01:58:43', 'A'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 02:01:32', 'B'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 02:15:44', 'A'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 02:57:44', 'A'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 02:59:44', 'B'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 03:15:44', 'B'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 03:27:44', 'A'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 03:31:44', 'A'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 03:45:44', 'B'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 03:52:44', 'B'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 04:01:44', 'B'),
    (TIMESTAMP '2021-04-17 04:23:44', 'A')
)
SELECT ts,
       id,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY ts
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM t
ORDER BY ts
```

See [this blog post](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html) for an explanation of how RANGE window frames work.